# Which is better for healing, power or crit?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

When making a healer, is it better to focus on power or crit in early/mid/late games?  Can someone provide some concrete examples with numbers on which is better in what situations?

Comment: Unsure about swtor yet (haven't gotten a heal), but in other games of this type - crit generally leads to over-heal.

Comment: @DavidB you beat me to the bounty I was going to add one later today.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All three healing trees have some amount of synergy with Crit, and will want to achieve at least some baseline amount.

*I've tried to use spell and talent names interchangably, often alternating between Republic and Empire talent names for the same effect. I always use both together the first time, and will generally alternate thereafter.*

**Mercenary/Commando** healers (Bodyguard or Combat Medic trees), will probably want to get to get enough crit to keep *Critical Reaction/First Responder* up as much as possible. This is a 5% Alacrity (haste) bonus that lasts for 6 seconds after a critical heal. Since most heals for this spec are Instant or 1.5 seconds to cast, and the lone exception is a 2 second cast. That means that you'll want somewhere in the range of 25-33% crit to have an average uptime of 100%, and probably a bit more than that for it to be a sure thing. This is the only class for whom Crit is *purely* a throughput stat.

**Operative/Scoundrel** healers (Medicine or Sawbones trees), get 2 Energy back from Diagnostic Scan crits thanks to the *Patient Studies* talent. Given the 'gated regen' model and HoT centric healing style of this class, DS is the primary 'filler' heal, and is used to fill free GCD's, and is an important piece of the regen puzzle that makes Operative healing work. Scoundrels also have substantial bonuses to Critical Healing further up the tree, making Crit a pretty desirable stat.

**Sorcerer/Sage** healers have the *Force Surge* or *Resplendence* talent respectively. This causes critical ticks of *Innervate/Healing Trance* to allow you to use *Noble Sacrifice* or *Consumption* **for free**. Both spells tick 4 times, and when used under the effects of *Force Bending/Conveyance*, a Sage will have a bonus +25% chance for each tick to crit. A decent baseline of crit from gear will minimize the frequency with which you find yourself casting Healing Trance without a Consumption proc. This is important, because Noble Sacrifice is the Sage's primary regen mechanic - being able to use it without a health penalty or regen penalty is critical to keeping your force pool full and having enough longevity to make it through the fight.

One thing to keep in mind in all of this is that you will *always* prefer your 'primary' stat (Aim, Cunning, or Willpower respectively) over either Crit or Power, as it provides both. Furthermore, you may well find, especially in the case of the Sorcerer that just this crit is 'enough' for you. Additionally, it's important to maintain a balance between Crit and Surge, as each of those stats make the other stronger. Surge increases the critical effect bonus of your spells. An important thing to note about healing in TOR is that unlike most MMO's, there is *no stat* that directly effects the size of any healers resource pool, or the rate at which it regenerates. The only stats available are 'throughput stats' that happen to function in a variety of ways. Alacrity allows you to heal more often, but at a cost to your resource efficiency. Crit allows your heals to provide much more throughput, but at a cost of predictability. Power provides less risk, but also less reward - consistent increased throughput and predictability. Another key consideration is that because of the resource model in TOR, all three healing classes rely heavily on HoTs, and in the case of the Trooper and Agent, on a 'filler' heal that has *no resource cost*, for which Crit is obviously very beneficial.

At the end of the day, healing is as much about style as it is about math, and different players are willing to accept varying amounts of 'randomness' in their playstyle. Adding additional crit will increase the variance in your healings effectiveness, while decreasing the variance in your regen for Sages and Operatives, and speed for Commandos.

Comment: I think this answer is worth the bounty.  It doesn't include concrete comparisons of stats, but does survey many abilities over many classes where crit should be considered specially - and it does that well.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't played healer in swtor, but speaking of experience from other games crit is not a desirable stat for a healer unless a critical heal results in a bonus of some kind (other than extra healing). The reason for this is that you want to be able to predict your healing out put so that you don't over heal and so you don't put faith in the randomness of crits

Comment: SWTOR values line up with other similar games, so yes this answer makes sense and applies for this game as well.

Comment: Granted, but I am willing to wait until I see some actual numbers.

Comment: Crit is a desirable stat for many healers in WoW as well. Modern MMO class design has come a long way from the traditional way where many stats were simply 'useless'. It's much more interesting this way.

Comment: there is a big differences between not desirable and useless, and the reason why it is a desirable stat for many healers in WoW is due to the added effects that they get talents.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the class and the skill tree you choose. Some skill trees and options expand on your crits.  Some classes even depend on crits to do the real healing so you're better off adding crit instead of power. But you need to analyze the skill trees you're using to see if they depend on criticals or not.
I've played Scoundrel and Consular to high levels, and if I remember correctly, the scoundrel depended more on criticals than the consular, but it might have been because of the skill path I chose.

Comment: All three healing trees have some additional benefit from crit. What varies is just how much benefit there is.

Answer (score 1):

Do the math - In SWTOR:

```
 +1 Primary skill -> 0.14 HP per heal
 +1 Power         -> 0.17 HP per heal
 +1 Crit          -> 0.017% better chance to crit
```

How convert this into HP? Consider the HP of your heals! Assume 70% surge +1 Crit results statistically into

```
  500HP heal:    + 0.06 HP
 1000HP heal:    + 0.12 HP
 2000HP heal:    + 0.24 HP
 4000HP heal:    + 0.47 HP
```

Now it's easy to decide when crit is a must have.

Comment: Both mainstat's and crit's contributions to healing/damage are non-linear, so your numbers are nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

In 4.0, Crit is **always** better than Power.  This is because Surge was merged into Crit, meaning that 1 point of Crit increases both your chance to do more damage as well as the actual amount of extra damage that is done.  Point for point, it contributes far more on average than Power does (even in the best gear currently available, when Crit is deeper into its diminishing returns).

Please see [this forum post](http://www.swtor.com/community/showthread.php?t=847112) for exact stat recommendations, as well as the mathematics and methodolgy behind them.